# git pull doesn't update files on pythonanywhere

Tags: python, django, git-pull, pythonanywhere

I am following Django Girls Tutorial, I am on html section - https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/html/ - where git is updated than files are transferred to pythonanywhere by using git pull. My git has been updated however, after git pull on pythonanywhere I do not see updated Files. I rerun my web app as well, no changes.

After git pull I see files changes, insertions and deletion, but no files updated in FILES section.

Thank You for help, 
Bogdan

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTp7l.jpg)

Comment: It's not clear what you are saying. That screenshot clearly shows the files that have been updated.

Comment: Looks like I messed up with files, double created some files.... I removed web app, deleted all files and run git clone from github. Than manually configured web app as per https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y4c4ickks2A . Now everything is updated.

Answer (score 0):

I found this if your willing to give it a shot. It allows you to reload and push all to your pythonanywhere site. https://blog.pythonanywhere.com/87/